# Iterating metadata.getColumnCount()

Tags: java, sql, indexoutofboundsexception, jexcelapi

Basically I am trying to read multiple queries from excel sheet through jexel and I am adding the cell contents to Key and Value in hashmap. For example

> A1=1  (Key) , A2 =2 ....
>
> B1 = "SELECT * FROM ABCD;" (Value), B2 = "SELECT * FROM XYZ;"

```
Map<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
    Cell rowObj1 =sheet.getCell(0, i);      
    Cell rowObj2 = sheet.getCell(1, i);
    sql =rowObj2.getContents();
    hashmap.put(rowObj1.getContents(), rowObj2.getContents());
}
```

Later I am getting the SQL(s) from the hashmap by iterating over rowCount on exel sheet.
Then I am adding all SQL(s) result sets to an array list
and finally I am iterating over array list size to get individual record set, at the same time get metadata for the record set.

However the problem here is I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
at com.bmc.arsys.jdbc.core.ResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(ResultSetMetaData.java:47)
```

on

```
int ColCount = metadata1.getColumnCount();
```

and here is the code snippet

```
ArrayList<ResultSet> arraylist = new ArrayList<ResultSet>();
int i;
String y;
for (i=1;i<=rowCount;i++){
    y = Integer.toString(i);
    sql =hashmap.get(y);
    rs  = st.executeQuery(sql);
    arraylist.add(rs);
    System.out.println(sql);
}

System.out.println("Array List Size "+arraylist.size());
for (int j=0;j<arraylist.size();j++){
    ResultSet rs1= arraylist.get(j);
    System.out.println("Record Set "+rs1);

    ResultSetMetaData metadata1 = rs1.getMetaData();
    System.out.println("Meta Data "+metadata1);
    int ColCount = metadata1.getColumnCount();
    System.out.println(ColCount);

    int k;
    for (k=1;k<ColCount;k++) {
        System.out.println("Record_Set "+rs1);
        while(rs1.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs1.getString(k));
        }   
    }
}
```

could someone please suggest where I am wrong.

Comment: It looks like your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` comes from your JDBC-Driver. What driver do you use?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am using "BMC Remedy AR System JDBC Driver" https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-22516

Comment: I tried the the same code but on different driver. When I use MS SQL JDBC driver the code gives me a different error com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set is closed.

Comment: Try putting  `System.out.println(rs1.getString(1));` before assigning meta data and colcount value